# Create a responsive diamond shape containing 4 separate diamonds with centered text

Tags: html, css

Ok, before I start, this is what I am trying to achieve using CSS3:

[image]

This consists of a responsive diamond shape container (a square, rotated 45 degrees) and four individual diamonds (originally squares but rotated with the parent element, obviously).

Apart from the 1px spacer between diamonds, I've managed to get the shapes to look how I'd like them to look, but I'm finding it very difficult to center align the letters in each diamond, as you can see from my [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39pq7dhy/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="cover">
    <div class="cover-logo-wrapper">
        <div id="cover-logo">
            <div id="cover-logo-box-1" class="cover-logo-boxes">
                <span>T</span>
            </div>
            <div id="cover-logo-box-2" class="cover-logo-boxes">
                <span>D</span>
            </div>
            <div id="cover-logo-box-3" class="cover-logo-boxes">
                <span>O</span>
            </div>
            <div id="cover-logo-box-4" class="cover-logo-boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#cover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

#cover-logo-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    height: 0;
    padding: 5% 0;
    border: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

#cover-logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding: 50% 0;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cover-logo-boxes {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.cover-logo-boxes span {
    display: block;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#cover-logo-box-1 {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}

#cover-logo-box-2 {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

#cover-logo-box-3 {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
}

#cover-logo-box-4 {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Please could somebody point out where I have gone wrong. I assumed using `translateY: -50%` would have been the winner, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.cover-logo-boxes span {
    display: block;
    transform: translate(-50% -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39pq7dhy/4/)

Comment: Congrats buddy you got the corrected answer. @akash

Comment: @SrinivasPai Thanks Bro :D yup

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.cover-logo-boxes span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;  //added this
    left: 50%; //added this
    top: 50%; //added this
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/39pq7dhy/3/)**

Comment: Never mind both will work. He can use which ever he wants.

Comment: @akash You could enhance your answer. Provide more context or explain  why you solved the problem this way.

Comment: I have remove some code. @gearsdigital My English is not so good I can't explain :S

Comment: Don't not worry about your english. Try to be understandable and write simple english. I'm sure some native speaker will fix your grammar. That's how SO works :)

Comment: Thank you for your input, @SrinivasPai. I went the another answer unfortunately, as the text in your demo is not 100% centered. Compare your demo with the other demo to see difference.

Comment: @gearsdigital Thanks I am still in leaning stage. Trying to improve myself. Thanks for your Kind advise

Comment: @PaparazzoKid I am glad it helped you. Happy coding.